# Number (proportion) of times var2 is uniquely associated with var1 using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set of purchases. Each purchase can consist of one or more products. I am interested in instances where a consumer purchases only one product at a time (solo-product purchases). I can calculate the number of time each product is purchased and the number of items in each basket.

I want to know what percent of the time a product gets a single-product purchase.

I need to use data.table because my real data in gigantic.

I have worked up a toy data set.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:13, basket_id = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8), prod_id = c(1,2,2,3,2,1,3,4,1,1,3,4,5))

# Count number of times each product is purchased
DT[,`:=`(NPurchased=.N),by=.(prod_id)]

# Count number of purchases in each basket
DT[,`:=`(BasketSize=.N), by=.(basket_id)] 

#Number of times product appears with a BasketSize of 1
DT[BasketSize==1,`:=`( NPurchSolo =.N),by=.(prod_id)]
```

I thought a next step would be to replace NA values with 0 in Norgsolo, but I get an error when I add

```
DT[is.na(NPurchSolo),NPurchSolo:=0,with=FALSE]
```

"i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657"

**Is this the best way forward? If so, what is my mistake? Or is there an easier way to calculate the number (proportion) of times var2 is uniquely associated with var1 using data.table?**

My desired output is a data.table with the entries

```
prod_id NPurchSolo NPurchased proportion_solo
1       1          4          .25
2       1          3          .33333
3       1          3          .33333
4       2          0          0
5       1          1          1
```

Comment: And I grabbed a colleague who pointed out that my first mistake is with=FALSE.But I am still not sure how to get from where i am to where I want to be. I know this question is now vague, but perhaps someone can see the path a bit more clearly than I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone posted an answer that got me on the right track, but now it is deleted. It allowed me to figure out the following. (Edit: The first line isn't really necessary.)

```
DT[, NpurchSolo := sum(BasketSize == 1), .(prod_id)]
FINAL=DT[, .(Npurchased = unique(NPurchased), NpurchSolo = sum(BasketSize == 1)), .(prod_id)]
FINAL[, proportion_solo := (NpurchSolo/Npurchased)]

> show(FINAL)
   prod_id Npurchased NpurchSolo proportion_solo
1:       1          4          1       0.2500000
2:       2          3          1       0.3333333
3:       3          3          1       0.3333333
4:       4          2          0       0.0000000
5:       5          1          1       1.0000000
```